# Searchin in bootstrap-vue table with pagination showing only the results in the actual page

Tags: search, vuejs2, pagination, vue-component

I am creating a `bootstrap-vue` table to show car listings using pagination, filters and Search.
I am getting the data through an external API and using axios to populate the table with the data.

For example, when I am on the second page and search for `car name` within the first page of the pagination, it will not find the results.

I tried different solution from other answers but it seems no one is working

This is the template code

```
<template slot-scope="row">
  <div>
    <b-form-group label-cols-sm="1" :label="search" class="mt-2 mr-2">
      <b-input-group>
        <b-form-input v-model="filter" placeholder="Type to Search">
        </b-form-input>
        <b-input-group-append>
          <b-button :disabled="!filter" @click="filter = ''">
            {{ $t('labels.frontend.listings.clear') }}
          </b-button>
        </b-input-group-append>
      </b-input-group>
    </b-form-group>
    <!--
    <input type="checkbox" :value="items.id" v-model="selected" />
    -->
    <!-- eslint-disable -->
    <b-table
      striped
      hover
      :items="items"
      :fields="fields"
      :filter="filter"
      selectable
      :select-mode="selectMode"
      selected-variant="success"
      @row-selected="rowSelected"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :outlined="outlined"
      responsive
      autoWidth
    >
      <!-- eslint-disable -->
      <template slot="selected" slot-scope="{ rowSelected }">
        <input type="checkbox" :value="items.id" v-model="selected" />
        <span v-if="rowSelected">✔</span>
      </template>
      <template slot="actions" slot-scope="row">
        <b-button
          size="sm"
          :to="'/account/cars/' + row.item.id"
          class="mr-1"
        >
          Information
        </b-button>
      </template>
      <template slot="delete" slot-scope="row">
        <b-button
          size="sm"
          @click="fireDelete(row.item, row.index)"
          class="mr-1"
          variant="danger"
        >
          <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true">
          </i>
        </b-button>
      </template>
    </b-table>
    <b-row>
      <b-col md="8" class="my-1">
        <b-pagination
          v-model="currentPage"
          :total-rows="totalRows"
          :per-page="perPage"
          class="my-0"
        ></b-pagination>
      </b-col>
      <b-col md="4">
        <b-form-group label-cols-sm="3" :label="page">
          <b-form-select v-model="perPage" :options="pageOptions"></b-form-select>
        </b-form-group>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</template>

and this is the script code

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectMode: 'multi',
      selected: [],
      filter: null,
      totalRows: 1,
      currentPage: 1,
      perPage: 15,
      pageOptions: [5, 15, 30],
      outlined: true,
      items: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get(this.$app.route('account.api.cars')).then(res => {
      for (let i in res.data) this.items.push(res.data[i])
      this.totalRows = this.items.length
    })
  }
}
```

The default search method provided with the boostrap-vue search only the results in the actual page, is there anyway to search for the other items in the pagination?

Comment: The default filtering for `bootstrap-vue` filters based on all pages/items and not just the page you're on. You can try it in their full example here: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#complete-example

Comment: I found this function can solve the problem                             onFiltered(filteredItems) {
        // Trigger pagination to update the number of buttons/pages due to filtering
        this.totalRows = filteredItems.length
        this.currentPage = 1
      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding this function to change the counter in real time by getting the length of the filtered item

```
onFiltered(filteredItems) {
    this.totalRows = filteredItems.length
    this.currentPage = 1
    this.items.count = filteredItems.length
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are fetching data from an api, I guess you are calling it with different limits and offsets, for every page. While, from the search box, you need to call the api that gives you back the whole list of data. Like this, you are able to search through all the cars (otherwise - default behaviour of bootstrap-vue search box -, you're just searching among the cars of that page - the cars displaying in that page === the api response for that single page). The same is for the filters. You need to adjust the default behaviour of vue-bootstrap according to the your needs, in this case according to your api responses.
This is my experience so far, hope it helps you.
xx

Comment: "The problem is that b-table isn't always responsible for paging. paging can be performed servers side in external JavaScript, so b-table might only know about the items that are currently shown only, and would not be able to maintain state with server side pagination or external client side pagination." from https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/4015 The problem in this issue is different, but it clearly states that "b-table might only know about the items that are currently shown only".